# Object in use System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#

I have problems calling `Form` objects from another class.

In `Form` class I have this:

```
public void reloadMapOverlay(GMapOverlay overlay)
{
    try
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(overlay)));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("reloadMapOverlay: {0}", e);
        this.setError("reloadMapOverlay: " + e);
    }
}
```

And in another class (Map_custom.cs):

```
route.Points.Add(coords.get_position());
overlay.Routes.Add(route);
mainForm.reloadMapOverlay(overlay);
```

When `mainForm.reloadMapOverlay` executes, vb gives me and object in use an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException

in overlay object.

What can I can do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please post the exception message and stack trace (to determine where exactly the exception occurs)? And this is c#, so why does "vb give" you an exception? And to do a guess: Is your `Form` shown at the moment you call that method? Or is it already closed? If it's not yet created or already closed (so no window handle exists), `Invoke` will throw that exception.

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace of your error message this will help significantly! 
But maybe you are just calling the `mainForm.reloadMapOverlay` from outside the UI Thread? To fix it you need to refence to the UI Thread using the Dispatcher from your MainForm. You could workaround this by storing a reference to the UI Thread dispatcher by calling `somePublicVariable = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` in the MainForm. And then calling `somePublicVariable.Invoke(() => mainForm.reloadMapOverlay(overlay))` in your Map_custom class

Comment: hi!!, ty for your  feedback!!! here is the error msg:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: El objeto ya está en uso.

Answer (score 0):

i try adding dispacher in mainForm, ->

```
public Dispatcher dispacher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
public void reloadMapOverlay(GMapOverlay overlay)
            {
                try
                {
                    dispacher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(overlay)));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("reloadMapOverlay: {0}", e);
                    this.setError("reloadMapOverlay: " + e);
                }
            }
```

and nothing.

---

i have
`public void reloadMapOverlay(GMapOverlay overlay)
        {
            try
            {
                Invoke(new Action(() => this.map_Box.Overlays.Add(overlay)));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("reloadMapOverlay: {0}", e);
                this.setError("reloadMapOverlay: " + e);
            }
        }` in mainForm,
then, in another class  (Map_Custom.cs) i have a function

```
        public void addRoute()
    {
        if (!coords.isWrongCoords())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Route");
            route.Points.Add(coords.get_position());
            overlay.Routes.Add(route);
            mainForm.reloadMapOverlay(overlay);
        }
    }
```

and in mainFrom i have a function (inside one thread) where i call

```
                            Thread addRoute = new Thread(new ThreadStart(map.addRoute));
                        addRoute.IsBackground = true;
                        addRoute.Start();
```